# Domain has an outgoing mail hold. Message will be reattempted later

Tags: linux, email, centos

Dejo esto porque me tomó mucho tiempo encontrar el issue.

A causa de una filtración de SPAM, mi servidor dedicado, bloqueo una cuenta interna y comencé a recibir el siguiente error:

`Domain [midominio] has an outgoing mail hold. Message will be reattempted later`

Escribo en la respuesta cómo lo resolví.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de limpiar en búsqueda de virus, checar blacklist, me seguía arrojando el error, hasta que encontré los siguientes archivos, en las rutas siguientes:

`/etc/outgoing_mail_suspended_users`

`/etc/outgoing_mail_hold_users`

En mi caso, en /etc/outgoing_mail_hold_users, se encontraba listado el usuario que no permitía el envío de emails, comenté el archivo y reinicié el EXIM.

Con eso mis correos volvieron a la normalidad.

Espero que si te topas con éste issue, está solución te ayude a resolverlo más rápido.